# Crazy unique_ptr syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I was recently using this syntax for a pointer:

```
std::vector<Shader *>* _shaderArray;
```

The problem is that I started to get memory leak errors. So now I decided to use unique_pointers, so I don't have to worry about this anymore. But from what I understood the above syntax in c++11 syntax is:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shader>>> _shaderArray;
```

If that is right, how do I initialize it? this code gives me errors:

```
_shaderArray = new std::vector<Shader *>( );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the `unique_ptr` at declaration,

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shader>>> _shaderArray{new std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shader>>( )};
```

Full (compilable) minimal example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Shader{};

int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shader>>> _shaderArray{new std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shader>>( )};
}
```

Comment: that gives me an error in "new". It says Error: expected a type specifier, since I have two unique pointer, maybe I should initialize both

Comment: The declaration above compiles without errors on my side (both g++ and clang). Make sure you use `-std=c++11` flag to enable `C++11`

Comment: I am trying to include this in a private member, but I does not compile here (visual studio 2013 express), I will try that

Comment: from what I've seen this features are all default enabled on visual studio, It does not work because I was trying to do that inside of a class definition looks like

Comment: I put the entire code above, a minimal example, which compiles on my machine. You probably have additional errors then. Does the above code compiles on your side?

Comment: yes it works, it does not work when I declare that line in a private member. But I already fixed that, thanks!

Comment: Ahh ok, you tried to declare it as a member variable, and you cannot initialize it, so, as @glampert pointed out, have to use an empty pointer declaration then `.reset` in the constructor, or use uniform initialization `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>> _shaderArray{new std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>( )};`

Comment: @vsoftco Sure it can be a member variable! It'd be initialized in the initializer list if it's an instance variable, or in the static member's definition if it's a class (static) variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, I would recommend the use of a `typedef` or `using` alias to simplify that very long statement:

```
using ShaderPtrVec = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shader>>;

using ShaderPtrVecPtr = std::unique_ptr<ShaderPtrVec>;
```

Then, using it becomes a bit more clear:

```
ShaderPtrVecPtr shaderArray( new ShaderPtrVec( ) );
```

Or, if you happen to have already declared the unique pointer but need to re-assign its contents, you can use [`reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset):

```
shaderArray.reset( new ShaderPtrVec( ) );
```